# How to get dispatch_after and dispatch_semaphore_t to work together in GCD?

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I'm getting curious about using `dispatch_after` and `dispatch_semaphore_t` together to execute some tasks and wait some time between each thread.

I use the following code:

```
dispatch_time_t time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 3ull * NSEC_PER_SEC);

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);

dispatch_after(time, queue, ^{

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    NSLog(@"blk01");

    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);

});

dispatch_after(time, queue, ^{

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    NSLog(@"blk02");

    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);

});

dispatch_after(time, queue, ^{

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    NSLog(@"blk03");

    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);

});
```

I'm getting the execution of threads after 3 seconds, not with the expected delay.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to execute threads in dispatch_semaphore_t with delay time between each thread execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to execute three blocks serially (not concurrently), and you want to pause between blocks, there are simpler ways than using a semaphore.  The simplest is to just create a serial queue and put a `sleep` (or `usleep`) at the beginning or end of each block:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("my queue", 0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    sleep(3);
    NSLog(@"blk01");
});

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    sleep(3);
    NSLog(@"blk02");
});

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    sleep(3);
    NSLog(@"blk03");
});

dispatch_release(queue);
```

Putting `sleep` in your blocks is very simple, but ties up a thread.  That probably doesn't matter unless you're creating a lot of queues and sleeping on many of them.

If you tell us why you think you need a semaphore, perhaps we can offer you a better alternative or advice on how to use it properly.

Comment: It works like a charm, nothing specially with dispatch_semaphore_t just curious and having the properly way to do that.

Comment: what if the block executing take more than setuped time ?

Answer (score 3):

Your code isn't asking for a 3-second delay between each invocation. It's scheduling 3 blocks, all at the exact same time, and all 3 blocks take the semaphore and log.

Either you need to adjust the time you're using for dispatching for each subsequent block, or you need to schedule subsequent `dispatch_after()` calls from within each previous call. The former is probably simpler, and will get you more precise timing. If you go with the latter be sure to re-calculate `time` in each block, because that refers to an absolute time, not a relative duration.

Comment: Yep, with several attempts it worked just adjusting the time. Thank you very much for the absolute/relative time explaination.